# Connect by Level & regexp_substr in postgres Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

Im migrating a query from oracle to postgres sql. Im facing issue with the function regexp_substr and from dual connect by regexp_substr. Here is the query ,

```
SELECT 
ID,
DATE,
ADDRESS,
NAME,
LASTNAME,
DATEOFBIRTH,
AGID
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 
App.AggId AS AggId, 
App.Id AS Id,  
App.LastName AS LastName, 
App.Name AS Name,
App.Date AS Date, 
App.DateOfBirth AS DateOfBirth, 
App.Address AS Address, 
FROM 
App App
WHERE    
App.DATE between {?DateCreatedFrom} and ({?DateCreatedTo}) and 
({?dFrom}=-999 or App.ID>={?IdFrom}) and
({IdTo} = -999 or App.ID <= {?IdTo}) and
({?AgId} = 'ALL' or App.AGID in (  select regexp_substr( {?AgId},'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr( {?AgId}, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null       ) ) and
({?LastName} = 'null' or App.LASTNAME = {?LastName}) and
({?Name} = 'null' or App.NAME = {?Name}) 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Please assist me to run this query in postgres

Comment: FYI: v9.2 and v9.3 are both end-of-life and therefore unsupported old versions. If you have the option to start with a newer version, you should do so.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
select regexp_substr( {?AgId},'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr( {?AgId}, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array({?AgId}, ','));
```

I'm not an expert at Oracle syntax, but I believe it's just splitting the string on ',' into multiple rows.

You could also use regexp_split_to_table, but it tends to be slower than unnest(string_to_array...